# Convolutional Neural Network: can't loop through DirectoryIterator

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a CNN image classifier using Keras. I have one folder with training images and another one with validation images but I have no definition of classes.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img,img_to_array, load_img
from keras.applications import InceptionV3

conv_base = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',
                    include_top=False,
                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

train_dir = 'MO444_dogs/train/'
validation_dir = 'MO444_dogs/val/'
nTrain = 600
nVal = 150

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 30 
train_features = np.zeros(shape=(nTrain, 7, 7, 512))
train_labels = np.zeros(shape=(nTrain,3)) 
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=True)
```

The code snippet above works all right. The problem begins when I try to use model.predict() function to pass the image through the network. Well, to be more precise, it begins a little before, in the for loop:

```
i = 0
for inputs_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
    features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
    train_features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
    train_labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
    i += 1
    if i * batch_size >= nTrain:
        break
```

This last snippet outputs this:

[image]

Basically the  `train_generator` variable is a `DirectoryIterator` object, yielding tuples of numpy arrays. So far I believe the error could have something to do with the fact that I have no classes defined, maybe? I think might be that because I found similar working examples like [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/keras-tutorial-transfer-learning-using-pre-trained-models/), but with folder defined classes, like Keras docs explains.

So far I am looking for alternative ways to do this loop but maybe I need to go another way entirely.

Thanks or any directions.

Comment: Yes, the problem is because it needs folder defined classes but I don't know how to work it out without them. Try doing this 
`for x in train_generator:
    print(x)`

Comment: Also, you can pass a list of your own classes with the `classes` argument in `datagen.flow_from_directory()` like `classes=['cat', 'dog']`

Comment: That's an issue. The classes are basically dog breeds, but they are unknown..I don't think I can guess them. I did the for loop you sugested, it printed out a big numpy array tuples, as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I rechecked my data and saw there is a class pattern in it. Só there is classes and I solved the issue with it.